# Return a specific type from for yield in Scala

Tags: scala, yield, for-comprehension

I am trying to use a function to call 3 separate APIs asynchronously and collate the responses into a `UserDetails` object and return this as part of the function.

However, the issue I am experiencing is that when I explicitly set the return type to `Future[UserDetails]` it does not compile as the return from the `yield` is not a `UserDetails` object and I can't work out how to return what I want from this.

Note I am looking to return a `Future[UserDetails]` but the inferred return type is `Future[Object]`

My code is currently as below:

```
def getUserDetails(userId: String) = {
  usersConnector.getUserById(userId).map {
    case Some(user) =>
      for {
        connections <- connectionsConnector.getAllConnections(user.username) recover {case _ => None}
        pendingConnections <- connectionsConnector.getAllPendingConnections(user.username) recover {case _ => None}
        userLocation <- userLocationsConnector.getLocationByUsername(user.username) recover {case _ => None}
      } yield {
        UserDetails(Some(user), connections, pendingConnections, userLocation)
      }
    case None => UserDetails(None, None, None, None)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the cases in your map function do not return the same type.
The `None` case returns `UserDetails`. However, the `Some` case returns a `Future[UserDetails]`. The least upper bound (least common ancestor) of these two types is `AnyRef`, that is, `Object`. As a result, the `map` function transforms the `Future[Option[User]]` into a `Future[Object]`.

There are two ways to resolve this. First is two use the `Future.successful` constructor in the `None` case:

```
...
case None => Future.successful(UserDetails(None, None, None, None))
...
```

Now, the resulting future has the type `Future[Future[UserDetails]]`. You only need to flatten it at this point:

```
...
}.flatMap(x => x) // add at the end
```

The second, more elegant way is to embed everything into the for-comprehension:

```
def getUserDetails(userId: String) = {
  def detailsFor(user: Option[User]) = user match {
    case Some(user) =>
      for {
        connections <- connectionsConnector.getAllConnections(user.username) recover {case _ => None}
        pendingConnections <- connectionsConnector.getAllPendingConnections(user.username) recover {case _ => None}
        userLocation <- userLocationsConnector.getLocationByUsername(user.username) recover {case _ => None}
      } yield {
        UserDetails(Some(user), connections, pendingConnections, userLocation)
      }
    case None => Promise.successful(UserDetails(None, None, None, None))
  }
  for {
    user <- usersConnector.getUserById(userId)
    userDetails <- detailsFor(user)
  } yield userDetails
}
```

EDIT:

See Łukasz's comment below about starting futures asynchronously in a for-comprehension.

Comment: Thanks, your answer fixes the issue I was having with return types! One question on the `flatMap`, should I have to `flatMap` and then `map` to get the value out of the `Future`?

Comment: You're welcome! To get the value out of the future, you should probably use an `onComplete` callback or `foreach`.

Comment: Thank you for adding the second method of doing this, leaves me with only one `Future` to handle so it is much more elegant!

Comment: note that `getAllConnections`, `getAllPendingConnections` and `getLocationByUsername` do not run in parallel. Just one by one. You probably want to store them in variables so they all start ~at once and then compose them in for comprehension.

Comment: Thanks for that addition @Łukasz, I did not know they would execute synchronously and assumed the for comprehension automatically ran them in parallel